# Redis Active-Active

Tags: kubernetes, redis-cluster

We have, in our company, two datacentres(on prem) running in two different cities/locations in US and working as a prod and DR mode(Active-Passive).

And planning to setup a Redis cluster running on these data centres at the same time in an active active manner.
We want to use redis as a distributed cache, not as a data store. User sessions and mostly read-only data will be stored there and make sure user sessions are maintained at both on prem datacenter redis cache.

On a daily basis two data centers should operate for both applications and Redis side(active-active). Applications will do read/write operations on Redis. Please let me know for any solutions for above on-prem setup.

Redis Active-Active Geo-Distribution (CRDTs-Based)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Redis enterprise on-prem should work for your use case. Is that what you are asking?